# How to set working directory in a Visual Studio 2010 project?

Tags: c#, working-directory

My project is in C# Windows Forms. While debugging, I was using the debug folder as the working directory but now that I will deploy my project I need to specify a working directory. How do I do it?

Answer (score 5):

You can set it *programmatically* with [`Environment.CurrentDirectory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.currentdirectory.aspx) - but normally it's simply determined by how the program is executed. For example, if you start the app by double-clicking on it, the working directory will be the one containing the executable. If you start it from the command line, it will be the current directory of the console at the time.

Why does it matter in your code, and what are you trying to set it to?

Comment: Because I use the current directory to store some files which need to be persistent during executions. The problem is that when I published the project and an installation file was created, it installs the program in an unknown location and I assume it's a temporary location because my files can't be found during different executions. Is there something better I can do?

Comment: @user579674: This sounds more like an installation issue than anything else, but you should also consider using the settings classes available in the framework, which can be used to store application or user settings. Also, don't forget that you can store files in places other than the current directory, of course...

Comment: The settings classes, are they just for storing classes/settings or can I also store files? What I want is to create a folder for the application (just like programs do for storing user files in documents folder). The way to do this is to create a directory with Directory.CreateDirectory() and then use Environment.CurrentDirectory to point to it?

Comment: Windows has certain folders for things like this.  Here is a list of the folder provided by the Environment.SpecialFolder enumerations: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to write or only read files?

For reading files, you may want to prepend `Application.StartupPath` to your filenames.

For internal settings files that will be both read and written, use `Application.UserAppDataPath`.

For user documents, use `Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), Application.ProductName)`

Comment: I need to both read and write files. Actually all files that are written should be read the next time the program runs.